# Swap position of <nav> and <section> on smaller screens

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have something like this in my page:

```
<header>
    <nav>
        a menu...
    </nav>
</header>
<section>
    some block...
</section>
<section>
    <article>
        article content...
    </article>
    rest of the page...
</section>
```

It's a standard webpage layout structure: menu at the top, then section with main topic (first `<section>`), then rest of the page (second `<section>`). On the desktop view it's ok.

Question: it is possible to replace with just CSS *navigation* block with first *section* block on a mobile device, so that main subject would be above the main top menu?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ypu can use (i) CSS media queries (ii) CSS flexbox (iii) order property to swap the order of elements without changing HTML:

```css
/*
 * change order of header and sections on smaller screens using CSS flex
 * use the stack snippet Full page button to view the "desktop" version
 */
@media only screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  #wrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  section:nth-of-type(1) {
    order: 1;
  }
  header {
    order: 2;
  }
  section:nth-of-type(2) {
    order: 3;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <header>
    <nav>Navbar</nav>
  </header>
  <section>Section 1</section>
  <section>Section 2</section>
</div>
```

Comment: Nice. So, this way we probably can even fool Search Engines for SEO practices, I guess (e.g. main text would be higher for SE, while user could see for instance big image at the top of a page)? (Except, of course for older IE browsers - checked it for IE9, not working there :P )

Comment: Yes, the flexbox attempts to solve various problems including source order. But flexbox support is limited: http://caniuse.com/#search=flex

Answer (score 1):

You can use `@media` to make the `nav` hidden. Try zoom in in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/akshay7/f7a15mem/)

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    nav {
        display:none;
    }
}
```

```html
<header>
    <nav>a menu...</nav>
</header>
<section>some block...</section>
<section>
    <article>article content...</article>rest of the page...</section>
```

Comment: Ok, that's hiding. What about replace menu, so that it was below first [section] ? Of course not in HTML code, but just displayed in such a way on a smaller screen.

Comment: @forsberg I don't think you can switch between elements but you can try position absolute and aligning it as you need